# Creating outer glow effect depending on the graduated symbology color of a shapefile - QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, symbology, line

I am working with a line shapefile that represents the road network of a city. I used a graduated symbology to draw each roads depending on their attribute value.

Now, I want to get the outer glow of each lines for visualisation purposes.
Going to `Symbology > symbol > effect` only allows me to add a outer glow effect to the whole network at one with a definite color. I, however, would like to have the glow color depending on the line it is linked to.

Here's an example in case I was not clear enough:

This is the network colored depending on the roads attributes values:
[image]

And this is what I get when I add the outer glow effect to it which is not what I am looking for: 
[image]

What I want is for the red roads glow to be red, for the blue ones to be blue, for the green ones to be also green etc.

Is there a way of doing so? I have been looking for a while and didn't come across any answers yet.

Comment: Apply the graduation again, then it should work. I tried it this way round (first blurring, then graduation).

Comment: It's unfortunately not working for me. What version of QGIS are you using?

Comment: Are you sure you're using `Blur`? Looks to me like you're using `Outer Glow` which indeed only allows to use one color / colorRamp.

Comment: @I.M. QGIS 3.4.13

Comment: Yes I just noticed my mistake, it's indeed ```Outer glow``` I am using here. ```Blur``` gives me a result that is too soft for the map I need to create. So from what you said @YoannQuenachdeQuivillic there is no way to get said result for ```Outer glow```?

Comment: For a stronger blur effect you may use several blur on top of each other....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two choices

- **Solution 1**: Geometry generator and ShapeBurst

Follow the accepted answer: [QGIS 3 How to Create Glow on Layer with Gradient Symbology](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/321795/qgis-3-how-to-create-glow-on-layer-with-gradient-symbology)

- **Solution 2**: Stack as many `Blur` effects as you need to get the desired result

[image: Effect Stack]

<sup>*Effect Stack*</sup>

[image: Result]

<sup>*Result*</sup>

Comment: I got what I wanted with the stacked blur effect, thank you.